# How to push commits from Gerrit to remote repository?

Tags: git, gerrit

I installed Gerrit, created a project, cloned the repo via SSH, committed my changes and pushed them back to Gerrit. Now I want to use Gerrit as a middleman between the developers and the main repository.

Is there a way to make Gerrit automatically push reviewed commits to another remote repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the replication plugin that is bundled with Gerrit. You find documentation within your Gerrit installation under the Plugins tab. One version of the docs can be found [here](https://review.typo3.org/plugins/replication/Documentation/config.html).